# button id cannot be retrieved/shown with getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am trying to make a calculator with Javascript/HTML/CSS and currently at the stage of trying to make the pushed button (using Bootstraps's button class) to appear in the display.

Part of  the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
     <button class="keys" id="7">7</button>
     <button class="keys" id="8">8</button>
     <button class="keys" id="9">9</button>
     <button class="keys" id="/"><img src="images/division.png" height="50em" width="50em"></button>
     <button class="keys" id="reset">C</button>
</div>
```

In the js file:

```
function calculate(evt){
   var keyValue = evt.target.id  // recording the key value into variable

   tempDisplay += keyValue;
   document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = tempDisplay;
}
```

The first 3 lines (7,8 & 9) are fine, the getElementById can grab the ids and shown them on the "display" section.

However I could not get the line with the image to show its id i.e. "/" on the display.

If I entered some kind of a text eg:

```
<button class="keys" id="/">text<img src="images/division.png"></button>
```

then the "/" can be displayed fine.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calculate(evt){


    e = evt.target || evt.srcElement;    
    var keyValue;  // recording the key value into variable   
    if (e.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
        keyValue=e.id;
    }   
    if (e.nodeName === 'IMG') {
       keyValue=e.parentNode.id;
    }
    tempDisplay += keyValue;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = tempDisplay;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `evt.target` will be the element that was clicked on.

```
 <button class="keys" id="/"><img src="images/division.png" height="50em" width="50em"></button>
```

In that case, that element will be the `<img>`.

If you want to get the ID of the button containing it, then you need to check its parent.

The general solution to this is to recursively check the `tagName` of the `parentNode` until you find a button or run out of parents.